# how to compare dates coming from datepicker?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angularjs-filter

I am trying to compare dates coming from a bootstrap datepicker and this format 11/05/2008. I tried using the Date.parse:

```
app.filter('dateRange', function(){
  return function(items, fr,to){
    var arrayToReturn = [];

    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){


      var testing =Date.parse(items[i].date) > Date.parse(fr) && Date.parse(items[i].date) < Date.parse(to);

      if (testing)
      {
        arrayToReturn.push(items[i]);
      }
    }
    return arrayToReturn;
  };
});
```

The filter is supposed to filter on a datefrom to a dateto range. At the moment I am having issues with comparing the date formats. How can I change the directive so I can compare the dates?

plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/gNswudddB6NY0dL55IR7?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

At least in your plunker the problem is that you're using a `date` field, which only accepts inputs in a `yyyy-MM-dd` format according to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D. This causes the from and to fields to be undefined in your filter, since the date isn't valid according to angular. Changing the input type to `text` solves the issue.

Updated plunker (try entering `01/01/2015` and `01/01/2016` for example):

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y0qRjK6Lujg3t4b0Wdle?p=preview

Comment: ok that datepicker does not popup anymore? also when I put in 1/1/2015 as the fromdate and 13/8/2016 as todate it should display both items in the data collection.

Comment: The datepicker doesn't pop up since there's no datepicker defined in the plunker, and you're not importing bootstrap either. Also, it displays the items if you input those. http://i.imgur.com/OPmqPge.png